# Check file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

If I open an external file like this:

```
$source = @file_get_contents('http://somewebsite.com/todaysinfo/');
$decode = json_decode($source, true);
```

How should I check if the http call was successful or not (page down or other)?

```
if ($source) { // will this re-load the page and check for TRUE return?

   // success

}
```

or could/should I do it like this (setting and checking the source at once)

```
if ($source = @file_get_contents('http://somewebsite.com/todaysinfo/')) {

   // success
   $decode = json_decode($source, true);

}
```

Comment: file_get_contents returns a string or false on error.

Comment: Either version is fine, the first one will not reload, the variable will contain the string, and if it failed it will be set to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if the server doesn't return HTTP 200, you should use cURL, since file_get_contents() doesn't care about the HTTP-Code and returns anything as long as the remote host isn't down.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://somewebsite.com/todaysinfo/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if(curl_errno($ch) == 0 AND $http == 200) {
    $decode = json_decode($data, true);
}
```

edit: Just with file_get_contents() and check if returned string is empty.

```
$source = file_get_contents('http://somewebsite.com/todaysinfo/');
if($source !== false AND !empty($source)) {
    $decode = json_decode($source, true);
}
```

Comment: Ok. An empty page would be enough for me to know that the call was unsuccessful. Maybe I should check if some steady var is present or not

Comment: Well, the most secure method is with cURL, since file_get_contents() returns a string (not empty) even if the remote host returns 403 Forbidden, 404 Not Found, 500 Internal Server Error or 503 Service Unavailable.

Comment: Hm ok, thinking. Thanks

Comment: So does `if ($source !== false AND !empty($source)) {` succeed if page is down or not?

Comment: If the remote host is down, file_get_contents() should return false. That doesn't apply if the remote host is available (server online and responds to requests) but the certain requested page not (deleted or something else).

Comment: Ok. Seems I should start using cURL (reluctantly).. I want to check the page/script and host for ANY string feedback (if there is response and not empty page = OK all good. Server down or empty page = NONO). Damn I'm confused about all this

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($source) { // will checking like this add a re-load?
```

No it wont.. 
And since file_get_contents returns false on failure, its a fine way of testing, except a page containg only space, 0 or is blank, will also be deemed a failure. This may not be what you want.

In that case you'd want to do:

```
if ($source !== false) {
```

Comment: Unless the remote host is down, file_get_contents() returns a string with the html code. It doesn't care if the remote host returns a 403, 404, 500 or anything else.

Comment: Ok. I'm always confused about triple equals.. !== means "it's false but it exists"?

Comment: !== checks if it isn't false AND if it's the same type. Read the php manual.

Comment: Same type as false (boolean).

Comment: @mowgli if you will put 0 in $source variable, and will use usual != operand, then 0 will be equal to false.

Comment: What would be NOT the same type as false (boolean)?

Comment: PHP thinks "0" and "" is == false. If you dont want it to think that, use "===" or its counterpart "!==". If you WANT php to think a blank variable is == false, only use "!=".

Comment: So what would `if ($source) {}` return on server down/moved/forbidden/whatever? False, right?

Comment: if page returned eg. 401 forbidden, but there is a content (eg. a text saying "go away") then $source == true.